# Javascript canvas and optimization of internal functions?

Tags: javascript, api, canvas

Say I have a rectangle that is 100 x 100 and I have a canvas 1000 x 1000.

As long as the rectangle's x co-ordinate is no more than 999 and no less than -100, it is true to say that some portion of the rectangle will be visibly seen on the canvas. Same goes for the rectangle's y co-ordinate.

What I would like to know is that if the rectangle's x or y co-ordinate is set so that the rectangle will not be visible on the canvas, does the internal workings of the canvas api still draw the rectangle or does it auto optimize and realise by itself that the bitmap that will be drawn on the canvas will not be seen, so therefore it doesn't attempt to draw it.

Comment: I guess that depends on the browser implementation whether a function call without visible result would trigger a redraw. Are you targeting something special? Why do you ask, do you have issues with it?

Comment: How about having a quick wade through the code, [Firefox's canvas code  is available](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e8a328c3e5bb/content/canvas/src) looks like it uses WebGL, so does that clip?

Comment: @Orbling using `experimental-webgl` is not the same as `2dcontext`, I am positive webgl might well handle the optimization as it is alot faster than `2dcontext`, but my question is `2dcontext` bound, I am afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When drawing to canvas the boundaries are checked for each draw. If a pixel ends up outside the canvas it is clipped (discarded).

If not you would get a memory corruption and very soon a crash.

Canvas is designed to be very safe so you won't have poorly written Javascripts (intentional or not) crashing your browser. The same applies to colors where color values (f.ex. using a bitmap array directly) are clamped to be within the valid range.

Optimization is dependent on the implementation, but it's reasonably to assume that if the area is completely outside the boundaries of the canvas, the draw operation is rejected in full. If it is partly inside it may start the internal block copy by moving start and end cursor to represent the effective area that would be rendered visible.

The other option is to check each pixel as it is rendered, if it's inside or outside the visible boundary. This however is not optimal.

To visualize, only the gray areas would be considered, the light-blue would be ignored:

[image: Canvas clipping]

(I didn't show all possibilities but it should be easy to imagine the bottom parts etc.)

Cursor here is where the internal routine will start and stop looping through the pixels. In this case if the area to be drawn is 100x100 pixels and is drawn at -50, -50 (x,y) then the internal cursor is set to +50, +50 relative to the area being drawn and the width and height is reduced likewise.

By moving the cursor and adjusting the width and height, it doesn't have to iterate through all the pixels and therefor optimizes the copy (although, it is not quite accurate to say "all pixels", as data is not copied per pixel but mainly on block basis related to memory alignment. There are separate algorithms that deals with optimized memory copying and takes into account offset bytes (bytes that does not start or end on a "clean" memory boundary) and so forth, ie. 4 or 8 bytes are copied in one go rather than one and one byte combined with masking (AND'ing the bits)).

The boundaries apply to lines and circles etc. as well. Their effective drawing area is handled as a square area, but there are different approaches to draw lines, circles than a square of pixels, to optimize further.

See f.ex. [Bresenham algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for lines or [mid-point circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) for circles or [various algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) for ellipses - I don't the specific implementation in each browser, but for these you square of the start and end coords and in some cases (as with circles and ellipses) you may have to check as you go (perhaps drawing the circle in four parts and check the part which is overlapping the boundaries on a pixel-individual basis - this is implementation specific though).

When it comes to translation that is merely a recalculation of coordinates (translate, rotation using [rotation matrixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and stuff like that). The new coordinates are then checked against boundary.

Now that being said it is not sure the browsers have their own specific implementation. They might use the system's native bitmap and clipping functionality instead where possible. However, the same described above applies in this case as well.

Comment: Very good answer thank you for this. Will award the bounty when it allows me too.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, On IE, Chrome and FF the fully offscreen draws (non-draws?) took about 100ms less than onscreen draws for 100,000 rects.

Comment: 100ms compared to what? Also it would be nice if you could link/post your test suite.

Comment: Greetings @Bergi! Not an exhaustive investigation here...I just found the question interesting enough to do a quick test! So I drew 100,000 rects fully off screen compared with 100,000 rects on screen to see if there was a time difference.  Quite frankly I expected to find no difference at all.  But I did discover a consistent but very small difference of about 100-200ms between on and off screen draws.  Anyway, for myself I will still do bounds checking on drawings.

Comment: But how long did it took for all, are the 100ms significant? And it would be nice to share the exact code so your tests can be confirmed by others - otherwise they're useless.

Comment: @Bergi: “otherwise they’re useless”.   Chuckle…I’m not suggesting you throw out your bounds checking while drawing to canvas—I’m not!    I’m suggesting that there is a small timing difference between draw rect(-200,-200,50,50) and draw rect(200,200,50,50).  In all cases the drawing completed in well under 1 second (but that would probably vary by computer configuration).   I’m not even attributing that difference to any browser optimization.  The usefulness, small that it is…is that there is a small difference.

Comment: OK, "*useless*" was the wrong term. I better had said "non-[reproducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducibility) tests are *worthless*". But as they show significance (>10-20%), you might should publish them. Btw, I'd guess bounds checking in JS is slower than the native one if you're doing them for every single draw (and not for whole objects)

Comment: I am going to start a bounty, I had exhausted tests like this myself to try and find the answer, but as @markE has pointed out; I think it is due to computer configuration as on xp, vista, 7, 8, mac os, ios, android etc I get non conclusive results.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [canvas spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html):

> "When the destination rectangle is outside the destination image (the scratch bitmap), the pixels that land outside the scratch bitmap are discarded, as if the destination was an infinite canvas whose rendering was clipped to the dimensions of the scratch bitmap."

This is not absolutely specific to your question but it's likely all "out of canvas view" operations are handled this way. So based on that, I'd say **Yes, they are "optimised"**.